# Putting tomcat access logs in SQL server database

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I have tomcat access logs with entries such as:

```
50.47.142.25 - - [07/May/2012:00:00:14 +0000] 0 "GET /mywebpage/blah.jsp " 200 123 "-" "-"
```

I wish to put all entries in a SQL table and then run SQL queries on it.

I am thinking of using GAWK (gnu AWK) to get all the lines in CSV format. Something like:

```
gawk '{print $1 ", " $2 ", " , " $3 ", " $4 ", " $5 ", " $6 ", " $7 ", " $8 ", " $9 ", " $9}'
```

gives me

```
50.47.142.25, -, -, [11/May/2012:08:51:02, 0, "GET /mywebpage/blah.jsp" 200, 123, -, -
```

Which gets me close to a SQL insert statement. Except, I need the datetime to be in the format:

```
2012-05-11 08:51:02
```

i.e no leading square bracket and the format SQLServer wants it to be in.  any tips?

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    monthlist = "Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec"
    c = split(monthlist, monthsarr)
    for (i = 1; i <= c; i++) {
        months[monthsarr[i]] = i
    }
    fieldlist = "1 2 3 5 8 10 11 14 15 17 20"
    fieldcount = split(fieldlist, fields)
    OFS = ","
}

{
    delim = ""
    c = split($0, logarr, /[ \[\]"]/)
    split(logarr[5], datearr, /[/:]/)
    ts = mktime(datearr[3] " " months[datearr[2]] " " datearr[1] " " datearr[4] " " datearr[5] " " datearr[6])
    logarr[5] = strftime("%F %T", ts)
    for (f = 1; f <= fieldcount; f++) {
        printf "%s%s", delim, logarr[fields[f]]
        delim = OFS
    }
    printf "\n"
}
```

Based on your sample log entry, the output looks like:

```
50.47.142.25,-,-,2012-05-07 00:00:14,0,GET,/mywebpage/blah.jsp,200,123,-,-
```

Quotation marks and square brackets are thrown away since they are used as field splitters along with spaces. Also, this creates a lot of false fields so I use a field list to iterate over.

Note that the `mktime()` and `strftime()` functions are specific to GNU AWK (`gawk`).